# jQuery ajax giving 500 Internal error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a jquery ajax request using

```
jQuery.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "some2.php",
                  data: { data: result }
                })
                  .done(function( msg ) {
                    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                  });
```

This code is sending request on `localhost` properly but when uploading on the server then it is giving error `500 internal error`

Live link is put at the link :

http://impulsesoftech.com/jaipurbus

my `some2.php` is

```
<?php
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
      return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
  } else {
      return $miles;
  }
}

$data = $_POST['data'];
$data = explode(",",$data);
print_r($data);
echo "Distance From Khandar Bus Stand : ".distance($data[0], $data[1], 25.992739,76.379046 "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
?>
```

What I am missing please help me

Comment: Doesn't look like enough information to help

Comment: Show the full code including URL path.

Comment: Have you tried omitting the `{data:result}` and replacing it with `result` ?

Comment: check your `some.php` , problem might be there

Comment: Your paths are probably not identitical in both environments.

Comment: Please add <!DOCTYPE html> above <html> in your page

Comment: Check your error handling and server-side logs to determine what the server error *actually is*.  JavaScript isn't causing it.

Comment: Just for future reference, a 500 error means that the problem is on the server side, so you need to look at your PHP code, not the Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please change

```
echo "Distance From Khandar Bus Stand : ".distance($data[0], $data[1],  25.992739,76.379046 "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
```

to

```
echo "Distance From Khandar Bus Stand : ".distance($data[0], $data[1], 25.992739,76.379046 , "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
```

you are missing a comma in `distance` function calling just before unit parameter .